# Oracle loader - error defining access parameters (KUP-01005)

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, sql-loader, oracle11gr2

I'm having problem querying the following table loaded from a file.

```
       CREATE TABLE "testTable" 
        (  
          "EAN" NUMBER(38,0), 
          "STOCK" NUMBER(38,0), 
          "SECCION" NUMBER(38,0) 
        )
        organization external
          ( default directory xtern_data_dir
            access parameters
              ( fields terminated by ';'
                badfile xtern_data_dir:'testTable.bad'
                logfile xtern_data_dir:'testTable.log'
                discardfile xtern_data_dir:'testTable.dsc'
              )
        location ('0025_STOCK.csv')  
      )
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
KUP-01005: syntax error: found "badfile": expecting one of: "column, enclosed, (, ltrim, lrtrim, ldrtrim, missing, notrim, optionally, rtrim, reject"
```

I have tried removing badfile, logfile and discardfile, but then I get another error, and I'm not sure how to make it work.

Please, help! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Avoid using quotes around table and column names.  That makes them case-sensitive and will cause you headaches later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use

```
 CREATE TABLE "testTable" 
        (  
          "EAN" NUMBER(38,0), 
          "STOCK" NUMBER(38,0), 
          "SECCION" NUMBER(38,0) 
        )
        organization external
          ( default directory xtern_data_dir
            access parameters
              ( RECORDS DELIMITED BY newline
                badfile xtern_data_dir:'testTable.bad'
                logfile xtern_data_dir:'testTable.log'
                discardfile xtern_data_dir:'testTable.dsc'
                fields terminated by ';'
              )
        location ('0025_STOCK.csv')  
      )
```